# Show that $\operatorname{Var}S^2=\frac{1}{n}(Е(X_i-EX_i)^4 - \frac{n-3}{n-1}\sigma^4)$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I have to show that $\operatorname{Var}S^2=\frac{1}{n}(Е(X_i-EX_i)^4 - \frac{n-3}{n-1}\sigma^4)$

Here's what I've got:

I know that $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{ \sigma^2} \in \chi^2_{n-1}$, so 
$Var S^2=\frac{2\sigma^4}{(n-1)}$

Also,

$Е(X_i-EX_i)^4=\operatorname{Var}(X_i-EX_i)^2 + \sigma^4$

I want to express $\operatorname{Var}(X_i-EX_i)^2$ somehow but I'm stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach. As you remarked
$$
\text{Var}(S^2)=\frac{2\sigma^4}{(n-1)}.
$$
Now note that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\left(E(X_i-EX_i)^4 - \frac{n-3}{n-1}\sigma^4\right)=\frac{\sigma^4}{n}
\left(E\left(\frac{X_i-EX_i}{\sigma}\right)^4 - \frac{n-3}{n-1}\right).\tag{1}
$$
But we know that $X_i-EX_i/\sigma=Z\sim N(0,1)$ and it is well-known that $EZ^4=3$ (for example by using moment generating/characteristic functions). In any case from (1) we get that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\left(E(X_i-EX_i)^4 - \frac{n-3}{n-1}\sigma^4\right)=\frac{\sigma^4}{n}\left(3-\frac{n-3}{n-1}\right)=\frac{2\sigma^4}{(n-1)}=\text{Var}(S^2).
$$
as desired.